# Electric field at distance from wire with current

Tags: emc

For EMC purposes I'm trying to estimate the electric field strength (V/m) created by current flowing through a wire. My idea is: first calculate H=I/(2*pi*r) and then calculate E=H*Zo, where I is current, r is distance, Zo is free space impedance (377Ohm). I assume far field and a long wire. Is this estimate valid or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Why? I am basically looking to get V/m from A/m in free space. If free space impedance has nothing to do with it, how else do I get V/m at a given distance from the wire?

Comment: OK, I see you mention far-field so maybe my original comment was hasty talking about induction.